# Eclipse - получить путь к проекту

Tags: eclipse

В Eclipse есть переменная `${project_loc}` (путь в ФС к проекту). Однако она определена только относительно текущего ресурса, то есть, например, файла, открытого в редакторе. Если же в перспективе нет ни одного открытого файла, то эта переменная пуста. Даже если проект - единственный открытый, и фокус находится на нём в Project Explorer. Отсюда вопрос: как получить путь к проекту в этом случае? Всякие варианты типа `${workspace_loc}/${project_name}` тоже не работают, так как и `${project_name}` тоже оказывается пустой.